# Some java script failed to load

Tags: magento2, javascript

[image: Take a look!]

So, the question is simple, what can i do to fix what you can see in that **picture**?

Some **js** are failed, not all of them, just those 5.

Comment: are these scripts are custom or default?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot a reasons why JS might not be loading on a site. In your case, it looks like these are core JS assets that are failing to load. So i would say the first thing you should so is recompile your files in the `pub/static` folders.

In your console run:

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

and then:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

to recreate all the front end files for the site. And then for good measure, run:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If you re-load the page and you are still finding that your JS isn't loading, i would then check the file permisssion and ownership of the `pub/static/` and `var/` folders to make sure that your web server can see the files and read them